# Are `After they had rowed` and `After they rowed` right?

Tags: grammar

- > **`After they had rowed`** a few miles across the Caribbean, they arrived at a small coral island.
- > **`After they rowed`** a few miles across the Caribbean, they arrived at a small coral island.

Are the above two sentences alright?

Comment: The first is better, because the arrival happened after the rowing was finished.

Comment: I see no particular reason to favour either version over the other in this specific context - where *After **rowing** a few miles across the Caribbean, they arrived at a small coral island* would be just as good (and *shorter*, which some might approve of).

Comment: I suspect there is a difference in preference here between British English (favouring “After they had rowed”) and American English (less inclined to use “had rowed” and quite happy with just “rowed”). As an Australian English speaker I can see both points of view but I’d side with the simplest construction, “After they rowed...”